# Using a structure definition in c

Tags: c

I defined structures in C like this:

```
struct cache_line{
    char valid;
    int tag;
    int LRU;
};


struct cache_set{
    struct cache_line *lines;
};


struct cache{
    struct cache_set *sets;
};
```

After these structures definitions, I define a function:

```
void do_something(struct cache_set *a_cache_set, int number){
            *a_cache_set.lines[next].tag = tag;
            *a_cache_set.lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
            *a_cache_set.lines[next].valid = 1;
}
```

In the main, I define a cache_set and do:

```
struct cache_set a_cache_set = my_cache.sets[setid];
int a_number  = 10;

do_something(&a_cache_set, a_number);
```

However, when compiling, I get the following error at the do_something definition (at

```
        *a_cache_set.lines[next].tag = tag;
        *a_cache_set.lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
        *a_cache_set.lines[next].valid = 1;
```

) :

```
error: request for member ‘lines’ in something not a structure or union
```

Yet, I explicitly declared a_cache_set as a cache set which contains lines...

What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing that `*a_cache_set.lines[next]`  should be `a_cache_set->lines[next]`

Comment: Operator precedence is (sometimes) important

Comment: @shuttle87 Without the leading star, but yes.

Comment: `*a_cache_set.lines[next]` --> `(*a_cache_set).lines[next]` or `a_cache_set->lines[next]`

Comment: @Zack, good catch on that typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an operator precedence issue.

```
    *a_cache_set.lines[next].tag = tag;
    *a_cache_set.lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
    *a_cache_set.lines[next].valid = 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
    *(a_cache_set.lines[next].tag) = tag;
    *(a_cache_set.lines[next].LRU) = *current_count;
    *(a_cache_set.lines[next].valid) = 1;
```

What you need is:

```
    (*a_cache_set).lines[next].tag = tag;
    (*a_cache_set).lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
    (*a_cache_set).lines[next].valid = 1;
```

or, better,

```
    a_cache_set->lines[next].tag = tag;
    a_cache_set->lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
    a_cache_set->lines[next].valid = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use `.` operator on a pointer. You have to use parenthesis to force dereference before `.`, or use `->` operator instead.

```
(*a_cache_set).lines[next].tag = tag;
(*a_cache_set).lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
(*a_cache_set).lines[next].valid = 1;
```

Option B:

```
a_cache_set->lines[next].tag = tag;
a_cache_set->lines[next].LRU = *current_count;
a_cache_set->lines[next].valid = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code `*a_cache_set.lines[next].tag = tag;` means the following:

1. get the `lines` member from a struct or union referred to by a variable named `a_cache_set`
2. do an indexing operation on `lines`
3. access the `tag` member
4. dereference the result from the previous operation
5. assign `tag`'s value to that dereferenced result

As it stands the very first operation in that list fails in your code as the variable `a_cache_set` is a pointer which is not dereferenced yet.

The fix is (as suggested already in comments) to dereference using `->` operator

Answer (score 2):

The operator precedence rules for C say that

```
*a_cache_set.lines[next].tag = tag;
```

is interpreted the same as

```
*(a_cache_set.lines[next].tag) = tag;
```

so, you are applying the `.` operator to `a_cache_set`, and not `*a_cache_set` as you probably expected.  Same problem on the other two lines.

The preferred way to write this sort of thing in C is with the `->` operator:

```
a_cache_set->lines[next].tag = tag;
```

In fact, it could be said that unary `*` being a lower-precedence prefix operator is why `->` exists.  (Contrast, say, UCSD Pascal, where you would write `a_cache_set^.lines`.)